# Draw arrow on svg path without using textPath

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I would position arrows on a different areas of a path. Actually I'm using `textPath`.

The problem of `textPath` is that it is linked with the path and I can't place elements between them ( for example a circle above path but under arrow  ). Also I'm limited to text characters to draw the arrow.

Is it a way to do the same thing without `textPath` I would use an arrow that I draw myself and place it on the line by respecting its direction?.

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <!-- to hide the path, it is usually wrapped in a <defs> element -->
  <!-- <defs> -->
<circle cx="75" cy="45" r="5" fill="blue"/>
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50"  />
  <!-- </defs> -->

  <text dominant-baseline ='central'>
    <textPath href="#MyPath" startOffset='100%' text-anchor='middle'>⯈</textPath>
  </text>

</svg>
```

Comment: I'm confused by the question. You already mention that you want to draw the arrow yourself. So... draw the arrow yourself? Or do you want someone else to draw the arrow for you?

Comment: The problem is not drawing the arrow, I know how to do it, textPath method don't allow to use a path only text characters ⯈.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is js solution:

```js
let len = MyPath.getTotalLength()
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t){
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  let p1 = MyPath.getPointAtLength((t/33)%len);
  let p2 = MyPath.getPointAtLength((t/33)%len + 10);
  let a = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI
  triangle.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${p1.x},${p1.y})rotate(${a})`)
}
```

```html
<body style="overflow:hidden;margin:0">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width=100vw height=100vh>
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50"  />
  <circle cx="75" cy="45" r="5" fill="blue"/>
  <path id=triangle d="m0,0 v-5l10,5l-10,5z"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't get the same thing as you. Here's my new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081911/svg-transform-attribute-place-elements-with-a-gap)

Answer (score 2):

The textPath method allows you to use a path for text characters
Can use unicode triangle symbol: `&#9205;` ⏵

- An example of an animation of the movement of one triangle along a
  path

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
 <circle cx="75" cy="45" r="5" fill="blue"/>
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50"  />

<text font-size="20"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="black" >
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath" startOffset='0%' >
 <tspan dx="0" dy="6">  &#9205; </tspan>
  <animate
    dur="10s"repeatCount="1"
    attributeName="startOffset"
    values="0%;95.6%"
    fill="freeze"/> 
 
 </textPath>
  </text>   
   
</svg>
```

- An example of animating the movement of several triangles

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <circle cx="75" cy="45" r="5" fill="blue"/>
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50"  />

<text font-size="20"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="black" >
 <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath" startOffset='0%' >
 <tspan dx="0" dy="6">  &#9205; </tspan>
 <tspan dx="-19" fill="red">  &#9205;  </tspan>
 <tspan dx="-19" fill="gold" >  &#9205; </tspan>
 <tspan dx="-19" fill="green" >  &#9205; </tspan>
 <animate  dur="10s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="startOffset" values="0%;89%" fill="freeze"/> 
 
</textPath>
  </text>   
   
</svg>
```

- An example of using other Unicode characters

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="100 100 400 300">

 <path id="pathTrain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>

<text font-size="32"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="black" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathTrain">
<tspan dx="0" > &#128645; </tspan>
 <tspan dx="-15">  &#128643; </tspan>
  <tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
  <tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
  <tspan dx="-15">&#128643;</tspan>
  <tspan dx="-15" > &#128645; </tspan>
<animate  dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="startOffset" values="55%;0%;55%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>    
   
</svg>
```

Comment: @infodev See another answer. The textPath method allows you to use a path for text characters

Comment: As I have explain it the problem with textPath is that it's linked with path. So if I would put in order a path then above it a circle. the textPath will be placed under the circle ( I would the textPath above circle )